# Setting property in array of Matlab objects

Tags: matlab

I am working with arrays of structs and objects in Matlab. I want to set properties for all the members of a certain array as fast as possible.

For the problem of setting a certain struct field, I reached a solution that involves using `arrayfun` and `setfield`. The following works like a charm:

```
myStru.id = 0;
myStru.name = 'blah';
arrayStru = repmat(myStru,10,1);  % Array of 10 elements. All of them have id=0
arrayStru = cell2mat( arrayfun( @(x,y)setfield(x,'id',y), arrayStru, (1:10)', 'UniformOutput', false ) ); % ids ranging from 1 to 10 :D
```

The problem is that, for objects, this does not work. I understand that `setfield` is for structures, so I have tried some other alternatives. The most excruciating error pops out when I try the following:

```
arrayfun( @(x,y) eval(['x.id=y;']), arrayOfObjects, arrayOfValues, 'UniformOutput', false );
```

(The class is a very simple one, which accepts empty constructor and has a real public property called 'id'). It results in:

```
Error using setFieldOfStructArray>@(x,y)eval(['x.id=y;']) (line 17)
Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an
assignment.
```

**ALTHOUGH** if I put a breakpoint in that line, it seems that the expression can be executed with the expected effects.

My two (three) questions:

- Why does the above solution fail? How can I get that to work?
- My final goal is to set properties **fast and simple** in arrays of objects. Which is the best technique for this?

(Note: I can write loops, but I always feel itchy when I have to do that :P)

Comment: I am surprised that it works if you use a breakpoint, but perhaps you don't break during the same call? Can you try running it with `dbstop if error` and see if it still works when you run this specific line?

Comment: A completely different kind of comment: If you don't want to write loops, have you considered using objects of arrays instead of arrays of objects?

Comment: Dennis: `dbstop if error` stops at that line, and I still don't know why executing the eval manually in the console returns the right result. The final solution, as you may notice below, was using the original `setfield` call.
Regarding your second comment, I have a complex hierarchy of objects that make use of polymorphism and that stuff. For some operations, having an object with arrays invalidates the rest of the design :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem may be that your propety may be readonly because setfield works also for classes.

Anyway there is some alternative, if your class inherit from hgsetget you can use set instead of setfield.

You can also use

```
subsasgn(x,struct('type','.','subs','id'),y)
```

instead of

```
setfield(x,'id',y)
```

Comment: Yes, `setfield` works indeed! I had two other unrelated problems which, combined, made me though it was not working properly. I promise to try the `hgsetget` inheritance other day, to see what happens :-)

Answer (score 0):

If can use cell of values, which will be automatically interpreted as struct array

```
>> s = struct('a', num2cell(1:10)', 'b', 's')

s = 

10x1 struct array with fields:
    a
    b

>> [s.a]

ans =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10

>> [s.b]

ans =

ssssssssss
```

Comment: No, I am interested in arrays of objects (not cells, not structs). Converting from one to the other is slow, and crashes with my original intention.
As an unrelated note, I am also interested in keeping dimensions consistent: in your example a 10x1 array is transformed into a 1x10 one (yes, I know you can use vertcat and all that stuff), but arrayfun and cellfun can help with this.